# how add new integer field into $project in mongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I need to add RoomId and BuildingId fields like this. The value1 and value2 are two integer variables. How do I code it?

```
$project: {
   "_id": 0,
   RoomId: value1,
   BuildingId: value2,
   "CalcItems": 1
}
```

thank you...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use $literal

Example:

```
$project: {
  _id: 0,
  RoomId: {
       $literal: value
  }
}
```